# scikit image perimeter returns zero

Tags: python, scikit-image

I am analyzing images (slices) from 3D CT scan. One part of the analysis requires the calculation of perimeter. Image is represented as 300x300 numpy array, and "objects" are marked with 1, while everything else is marked with zeros. The problem occurred when small object (two pixels) appeared, near the boundary of the image - calculated perimeter = zero:

```
image[0:1, 190:192]=1
from skimage import measure
rp = measure.regionprops(image)[0]

rp.perimeter
Out[32]: 0.0
```

Comment: If it is at the edge of the image, I think it is best to eaxclude it from processing altogether. After all, how do you know the shape of it when you are not imaging it?

Comment: Sometimes it's appropriate to temporarily add a 1-pixel black border.

Comment: the border could change the results, however, it seems odd to calculate zero perimeters without such a workaround...